# Tornado application structure with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

What is the right structure for a Tornado application with unit test?

Answer (score 3):

This is a subjective area.

I can only speak for myself here but I have a 'test' folder at the same level as my 'handler' and 'static' folders.

[Tornado sample project](https://github.com/bootandy/tornado_sample/tree/master/sample)

Comment: thanks for your code sample.I have just read it and i find that you use pymox to mock the third api.But the code is written two years ago.Is it possible or better to use some other techs,like the unittest.mock??

Comment: Python mocking libraries normally come down to personal preference, try whatever you fancy.